# What is the most ancient form of Armenian verb 'to be'?

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, indo-european, armenian

The  infinitive form of the verb in Eastern Armenian (provided there are infinitives) is a suppletive 'linEl'. I am surprised to notice its resemblance to most Finno-Ugric words of similar meaning, e.g.

> ```
>    Finnish     lienee    (Potentialis of olla = to be in 1st p.sg. affirmative)
>    Hungarian   lenni     (to be)
>    North Sami  leat      (to be)
>    Komi        [lony]    (to become, to be, to turn into)
> ```

What are the oldest records of the Armenian verb? Are there any correlates in Iranian and/or Paleo-Balcanic languages? Or maybe there are some correlates with languages from Anatolian group?

Comment: What are the easternmost Finno-Ugrian languages?

Comment: Well Erzya / Moksha / Mordvin would be the closest to Armenia...

Comment: I am not a fan of these languages.

Answer (score 7):

The oldest attested form is Old Armenian լինիմ (linim), whose origin in uncertain. Possibly derived from PIE **ḱley-* "to lean", whence Ancient Greek κλίνω, Latin *clino*. See [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%AC%D5%AB%D5%B6%D5%AB%D5%B4) for more.

The descendant of PIE **h₁ésmi* is եմ (em).

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%AC%D5%AB%D5%B6%D5%AB%D5%B4#Old_Armenian) the ultimate origin of the Armenian word for *to be* "լինել" (linel) is unknown.

Old Armenian had such forms as լինիմ, լինենամ, and back to the earliest known *լէնիմ (lēnim) - which looks to be a hypothetical form from its asterisk.

If you follow links around the Armenian and Old Armenian entries you will find some other words. "To be" is a pretty fuzzy word over time in most languages and can float around concepts such as existence on one hand, a mere syntactic copula on another hand, and then there can be senses like "there is" which can blur into words that also mean "stand", "lie", etc.

Answer (score 1):

In PIE the verb was e̯esmi/e̯essi/e̯esti (I/you/he is). As such the Armenian word cannot be inherited from PIE.

Comment: OK, so this is more like a Hittite paradigm; but what is the ancient Armenian form?